# Bigquery Partitioned Table Query for column names

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery Partition tables like sftp_data.sgp_v3_*.... here * means data is date wise for example 20220901 and 20220902....

Actually in 20220901 table there is a column name **email**... and in 20220902 column name is **e_mail**
I am having the problem to call **email** as my final column while doing SELECT * FROM sftp_data.sgp_v3_*...i want data from both email and e_mail... but for e_mail i am getting nulls..

Please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: Why can't you just recreate one of the tables with correct column name?

Comment: Try `SELECT * EXECPT(email,e_mail), COALESCE(email,e_mail) as email FROM sftp_data.sgp_v3_*`